Paste function not working--in any mode, program or app
I delayed updating to LTS 24.04. I keep my OS and other apps up to date. I suddenly lost the paste function after one of the last system updates to LTS 22. The copy function seems to be working. I cannot paste ANYTHING using the right-click menu option or CTRL-V. I cannot paste in Libre Calc,as an example. If I copy a cell and select another cell to paste, there are the dancing ants around the original cell, indicating the copy worked, but the paste function does not work. However, if I try to close the file, I have to select Save or discard changes, which tells me something went into the cell.
If I try to copy text from anything and paste it into anything, it will write. If I copy a link and got to Firefox and select Paste and go, nothing happens.
Note that this is only affecting the Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V clipboard. Select to copy and middle click to paste work normally.
Update: as mysteriously as this problem appeared, it fixed itself without any intervention by me, but has now returned. It seems to be intermittent. I do keep my system as updated as possible.

I forgot to include that I upgraded to LTS 24.04 and still cannot paste anything.

I found that copy/paste works if made immediately. But if I copy text (or make screenshot), then type some text in messager, and then try to paste - doesn't work. Extreamly annoying. :( It's a clean Ubuntu 24.04 setup, not upgrading.
